# Clustering in R - Clara

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I just started using R and was trying to cluster with Clara. I am not getting quite the results I had hoped for, and was wondering where I could find the details of the implementation of the algorithm and the necessary pre-processing? More specifically I wanted to clarify:

1. How does Clara handle discrete nominal data? If there are 5 categories, does it convert it into 5 binary attributes?
2. Does Clara first run PCA and then run the clustering on the principal components or are the PCA figures I often see just introduced for visualisation purposes?

Any insight into the algorithm would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This may be hard for people to answer. Can you say more about your data, your situation, & your goals? Can you paste in your code? In what sense were you "not getting quite the results [you]  had hoped for"?

Comment: Hi Gung, I am importing a CSV of 100,000 data points and 30 dimensions. Then I am just running Clara using k in range 3 to 6, eucledian metric and that's about it. The initial problem I had was that the clusters were all discriminating along one feature, which happened to be that of highest variance. As such, when I get back in front of the data I will try standardising (I thought this was the default!). I assume this will improve performance.

Comment: However, I am still left with the question of whether I should make categorical dat that is in no particular order into binary attributes? Or does the code do this? Equally I have seen plots of Clara output in terms of principal components. I was wondering if Clara did the PCA before the clustering as if it does not I would like to. For visualisation purposes this would make sense. I guess my problem is not so much the stats but I do not know where to get basic info on how Clara works (currently a black box to me). Thanks

Comment: Do you have a mix of continuous and nominal data? If so, you cannot use Euclidean distance. I doubt Clara normalizes your data for you (although I don't know anything about Clara). You should normalize your data yourself before you do any clustering. That's pretty standard.

Answer (score 2):

Euclidean distance is defined on numerical values.

When you pass non-numerical data, you *need* to check what the implementation does. Carefully check, *do not rely on vague information from third sources*: this may have changed across versions.

Three obvious approaches:

- ignore non-numerical attributes
- fall back to Hamming distance
- use one-hot-encoding (= Hamming distance * 2 unless weighted, so this is not an approach to be used lightly)

I doubt CLARA will automatically normalize your data. I would consider this a *bug*. Good normalization requires care, and cannot be done automatically.

Comment: Thank you. The Hamming distance looks very useful. 

I guess my issue is how I determine what the implementation does? The only way I can think of is to use dummy data? However, if I knew where the source code was or similar this may be a better approach.

Comment: I was also wondering whether clustering before or after PCA makes any difference? I was just trying to come up with a toy problem for this without success...

Comment: To find out what the implementation does, use the **documentation** and the **source code**, of course. Hamming wasn't really a recommendation. It's usually too coarse to be useful.

Comment: PCA (when done well) does make a substantial difference if you have correlated data with variance differences.